# Chain rule and product rule for computing Hessian from second differential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I want to compute compute the Hessian of $f(\mathbf{X}) : \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I've computed the first differential, which has the form:
\begin{align*}
df = t(\mathbf{X}) \ vec(\mathbf{X})^T \mathbf{A} \ dvec(\mathbf{X})
\end{align*}
where $t(\mathbf{X})$ is a scalar function of $\mathbf{X}$ and I can compute $dt = vec(\mathbf{Q})^T dvec(\mathbf{X})$. But I'm not sure how to put everything together into a quadratic form (where $\mathbf{H}$ is the Hessian):
\begin{align*}
d^2f = dvec(\mathbf{X})^T \ \mathbf{H} \ dvec(\mathbf{X}).
\end{align*}
How do I represent $\mathbf{H}$ in terms of $t(\mathbf{X}), \mathbf{A},$ and $\mathbf{Q}$?

Similarly, suppose I have a first differential of the form:
\begin{gather*}
dg = u(\mathbf{X})\ vec(\mathbf{A})^T dvec(\mathbf{X}),
\end{gather*}
where I have $du = vec(\mathbf{R})^T dvec(\mathbf{X})$. Again, I want to write out the second differential in terms of the Hessian:
\begin{gather*}
d^2g = dvec(\mathbf{X})^T \ \mathbf{H} \ dvec(\mathbf{X}).
\end{gather*}

If $t(\mathbf{X})=u(\mathbf{X})=1$, I think we get $\mathbf{H}=\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{H}=\mathbf{0}$, respectively, but I don't know how to handle the scalar functions when they depend on $\mathbf{X}$.

Comment: In order to obtain a working product or chain rule, you will either need to simply think of $f$ as a map from $\Bbb R^{mn} \to \Bbb R$ (so that our matrices $A \in \Bbb R^{m \times n}$ become vectors $vec(A) \in \Bbb R^{mn}$), or you will need to deal with the [Frechet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative)

Comment: So suppose I define $\mathbf{Z}=vec(\mathbf{X}) \in \mathbb{R}^{mn}$, and compute $df = t(\mathbf{Z}) \mathbf{Z}^T \mathbf{B} d\mathbf{Z}$ and $dt = \mathbf{R}^T d\mathbf{Z}$. Then how do I get $d^2f = d\mathbf{Z}^T \mathbf{H} d\mathbf{Z}$, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow me to use vectors to denote the vectorized matrices, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
 q &= {\rm vec}(Q) \cr
 x &= {\rm vec}(X) \cr
 &\ldots {\rm etc} \ldots
}$$
Now write the differential in terms of the Frobenius (:) product
$$\eqalign{
 df &= t\,(x^TA)\,dx \cr
    &= t\,(A^Tx):dx \cr
}$$
So the gradient is
$$\eqalign{
 g &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= t\,(A^Tx) \cr
}$$
To find the Hessian, begin with the differential of the gradient
$$\eqalign{
 dg &= dt\,(A^Tx) + t\,(A^Tdx) \cr
    &= (q^Tdx)\,(A^Tx) + (t\,A^T)dx \cr
    &= [(A^Tx)q^T + (t\,A^T)]\,dx \cr
    &= A^T(xq^T + tI)\,dx \cr
}$$
Yielding the Hessian as
$$\eqalign{
 H &= \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &= A^T(xq^T + tI) \cr\cr
}$$
Your second question can be answered in the same way.